# Why can't I defun "nil" as a function name

Tags: symbols, defun

I know that `nil` is a *constant* so its [*value cell*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#index-value-cell) cannot be changed, 
but why its [*function cell*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#index-function-cell) cannot be set as well?

```lisp
ELISP> (defun t ())
t
ELISP> (defun nil ())
*** Eval error ***  Cannot define ‘nil’ as a function
```

Comment: I am reading Chapter 9.1 in the *GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual*, so I come up with this question. This may not be a meaningful question, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's hard-coded:

```el
(defmacro defun (name arglist &rest body)
  "..."
  (declare (doc-string 3) (indent 2))
  (or name (error "Cannot define '%s' as a function" name))
  ...)
```

I'd suggest it would be rather unwise to define a `nil` function, and this protection prevents it from happening accidentally, so that seems sensible to me.

I note that you can't do it by bypassing `defun` either, as `fset` also guards against this.  Evidentially not everyone agrees that it's worth the CPU cycles to protect people against doing this, but this is how things are at present:

```c
  if (NILP (symbol) && !NILP (definition))
    /* There are so many other ways to shoot oneself in the foot, I don't
       think this one little sanity check is worth its cost, but anyway.  */
    xsignal1 (Qsetting_constant, symbol);
```

Comment: Bug reports https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25110 and https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25166 are both related.

Answer (score 3):

From a language design point of view, Emacs Lisp accepts `nil` as a parameter to functions to mean “do nothing” or “do some sensible default” or “turn it off” in a lot of contexts. Being able to assign a value or a function to `nil` could be very confusing. For example, `(fset 'func nil)` is equivalent to `(fmakunbound 'func)` — but if `nil` could be a valid function after running `(fset nil 'nil-func)`, then `(fset 'func nil)` should be equivalent to `(defalias 'func 'nil-func)`. So which of the two wins? Or should `(fset nil 'nil-func)` cause every undefined function to run `nil-func`?

Until and including Emacs 25.x, you could set the function cell of `nil`, leading to weirdness such as what I posted above. This was reported as [bug #25110](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25110): actually calling `nil` as a function didn't work. The bug was fixed in Emacs 26.0 by forbidding to set the function cell of `nil`.

It's arguably a documentation bug that this doesn't seem to be mentioned in the manual (presumably where it discusses [constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Constant-Variables.html)). But that's a very minor omission, since defining `nil` as a function isn't something one would naturally want to do, given that it doesn't have clearly-defined behavior.